# How to change routes dynamically based on route availability on Linux?

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, linux-networking, failover

I have an odd and somewhat specific routing question. I want to change routes/next-hop based on next-hop availability.

My setup is quite odd, and probably a far cry from any best practice.
It looks somewhat like this:

```
                               +---------------+
                               |  VPN Box 1    |   VPN Net 1
                      +-------->  192.168.1.177+---------------------+
                      |        |               |                     |
                      |        +---------------+                     |
                      |                                              |  Remote site
+--------------+      |                                             +v----------------+
|              |      |         +--------------+                    |                 |
|              |      |         | VPN Box 2    |    VPN Net 2       |  VPN Router     |
|    Router    +------+---------+ 192.168.1.178+-------------------->  Terminates all |
| 192.168.1.1  |      |         |              |                    |  VPNs           |
|              |      |         +--------------+                    |  192.168.32.0/24|
+--------------+      |                                             |                 |
                      |                                             |                 |
                      |                                             |                 |
                      |         +---------------+                   |                 |
                      |         |  VPN Box 3    |    VPN Net 3      +--^--------------+
                      +---------+  192.168.1.179+----------------------+
                                +---------------+
```

My `192.168.1.1` router is a Linux based one and have routes like this:

```
192.168.32.0/24 via 192.168.1.179 dev eth1  metric 1
192.168.32.0/24 via 192.168.1.178 dev eth1  metric 2
192.168.32.0/24 via 192.168.1.177 dev eth1  metric 3
```

I would like my routes to be updated based on VPN availability. Eg if the 192.168.1.179 VPN link goes down I would like either its metric to be increased, or it being removed/disabled.

My VPN router on the remote site is not able to run OSPF/RIP/BGP.

Is it at all possible to do something automatic only using iproute2/iptables/standard GNU/Linux utilities?

PS: I may be able to install an OSPF/RIP/BGP daemon on VPN Box 1 and 2, but Im not sure if that helps anything.

Edit: Is a script/program on the `192.168.1.1` router pinging the VPN IPs of VPN Net 1/2/3 and changing the metric/deleting the route the only/simplest/best solution?

Edit 2: PPS: I do not mind about connection tracking and graceful failover of established connections.

Comment: You can script this out but basically you are trying to reinvent OSPF.

Comment: It's certainly a strange setup. Assuming that each of your VPN machines delete their route through the VPN link if the link goes down, I would probably just add routes to the VPN boxes pointing to the others, 1 -> 2 -> 3. Then point your router at 1, and each packet will cascade through until it finds its way